# Get count of values entered in a loop. Calculate Std Dev

Tags: java

I am working on a school assignment, so I need some guidance on this. I am trying to write a program that reads a set of floating point data values from input. When the user indicates the end of the input my program must return the count of the values, the average, and the standard deviation.

I am able to the build the while loop to get the input and perform all of the other math functions. However, what I cannot figure out is how to get the count of the values entered by the user.

Here is what I have so far (minus the loop)

```
        /**
    This class is used to calculate the average and standard deviation
    of a data set.
    */

    public class DataSet{

        private double sum;
        private double sumSquare;
        private int n;

        /**Constructs a DataSet ojbect to hold the
         * total number of inputs, sum and square
         */

        public DataSet(){

            sum = 0;
            sumSquare = 0;
            n = 0;
        }

        /**Adds a value to this data set
         * @param x the input value
         */

        public void add(double x){

            sum = sum + x;
            sumSquare = sumSquare + x * x;

        }

        /**Calculate average fo dataset
         * @return average, the average of the set
         */

        public double getAverage(){

            //This I know how to do

            return avg;

        }

        /**Get the total inputs values
         * @return n, the total number of inputs
         */

        public int getCount(){

//I am lost here, I don't know how to get this. 



        }

    }
```

I cant use Array because we are not that far on the classes yet.

Comment: increment n on the add method, return n in getCount

Comment: Micho is correct - Micho, make that an answer so Jose can accept it.

Comment: Wait a second: you can't calculate std dev by just keeping a running sum of squares! Std dev is the sum of squared *deviations of each value from the mean*. You need to keep all the data points and calculate that in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        public void add(double x){
          sum = sum + x;
          sumSquare = sumSquare + x * x;
          n++;
        }

        public int getCount(){
          return n;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help and suggestions. It worked perfectly

Answer (score 2):

Unless I misunderstand the question all you need to do is have a counter int. Every time add() is called you increase the counter using counter++;

EDIT: Your int n seems to be the intended counter. I'd change it to something more descriptive (like counter as suggested). Having a field which is a single letter is pretty bad practice.

Then all you have to do is return counter in your getCount method.

Comment: +1 for better variable name suggestion. Readable code is better code.

Comment: Exactly! The first time I read through the code I didn't realise there already was a variable intended to count (which is why I edited my answer). If you don't know what a variable represents when you first see it, then it probably needs to be renamed.